# Cannot create large two-dimensional non-sparse Numpy arrays in Python using PyCharm on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pycharm, heap-memory

I need to create large two-dimensional non-sparse numpy arrays in Python using PyCharm but have been getting error when I go well beyond the dim = 110000.

dim = 110000

subcapmat = np.zeros( (dim,dim), dtype='uint8')

This is on Windows 7 and PyCharm is 64 bit. I tried increasing heap size but no luck. The system has 16 GB RAM (physical). I do not see this issue on a Macbook Pro just with 16 GB RAM (physical) where I can even create 2-d arrays with 500,000 x 500,000 without memory error.

I think I have tried all options that I could find here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. Please know that this is a dense matrix so I cannot use Scipy.

Please help.

Comment: 500,000 x 500,000 of uint8 is *250GB* of data, I doubt you could fit that in *16GB* of ram. In 16GB of ram you won't fit more than 16,000,000,000 8-bit values so around 126,000x126,000.

Comment: you are right. a large amount of memory will be needed if the allocation is limited by physical memory (which probably may be the case with Windows). on my Macbook Pro with 16 GB RAM, (just tested) I can create and use an array of size 11,000,000 x 11,000,000. There is a magic about OSX that Windows does not seem to have and I am stuck with Windows at my work.

Comment: 11Mx11M of unit8 is about **121TB**.  Unless you have one hell of a hard drive, I think Penn and Teller have a word for that sort of "magic."

Comment: The magic is that it didn't allocate any memory? @harris, these are the signs that you probably need to re-design your algorithm.

Comment: Your calculation makes sense and my hard drive is no more than a TB on OSX. I "allocated" but did not use 11 M x 11 M (as you said that probably did not actually allocate) but am happily using three 500K x 500K matrices in my work on OSX.

Comment: Some folks advised me to go to PySpark that I've never used but the fact that OSX seems to be able to do it indicates to me there may be a solution if I find out a means to make some adjustments in virtual memory management in Windows. First I thought it's heap vs. stack but learned that Python allocates all memory on the heap.